# Prolem with creating Spring project in Intelij over and over

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning Spring, creating a project that will work drives me crazy for a few days, it takes me all day to solve a number of problems and then when creating the next project, I repeat the previous procedure, but new problems appear. Im using InteliJ and I will write step by step how I create a project and what are the erros. I hope someone will help me because I am really frustrated.

New Project and I choose `Java Enterpise`, project template is `Web application`, build tool `Maven`. For Libraries and frameworks is automatically selected `Servlet` and I don't change anything there. Thats it, I created project. Now when I right click on project I choose `Add framework support`, I add: `Spring, SpringMVC, Hibernate`. InteliJ downloads it automatically. If anyone has time to explain this to me in a private message step by step how to set it up properly I would be very grateful.

`Spring version 5.2.3 RELEASE`
`Spring MC 5.2.3 RELEASE`
`Hibernate 5.4.11`
All Jar files have been added to the lib folder

Then I created `HomeController:`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/showHome")
public String showHome(){

    return "home";
}
}
```

`Componet scanning, mvc view, etc.`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- Add AspectJ autoproxy support for AOP -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.demo"/>

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <property name="user" value="springstudent"/>
        <property name="password" value="springstudent"/>


        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.demo"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"/>


    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->


</beans>
```

`web.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`Erros:`

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml]
```

Comment: Error message says you have a mistake in your xml file definition - but anyways why are you learning your way around spring using harder/older way of configuring beans via .xml files? pick up any book that was printed after 2018 and they will all be using java configuraiton - it will make it easier for you to learn

Comment: In most case during the course we cover both ways and usually use java configuration. Do you have some tutorial how to properly create web aplication with spring in intelij?

Comment: If you are learning Spring, you might want to start with Spring Boot to make things easier and start your project from https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Anything by baeldung, specifically this page is a collection of small topic based tutorials https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tutorial - I would recommend to supplement it with some beginner friendly book, for example Spring in Action